# Ajax Response: [readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"]

Tags: ajax, jquery

My ajax call is resulting in error. Here is the info that I could get in error callback:

```
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
status: 0
statusText: "error"
```

What does that mean? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my ajax call:

```
var ajaxurl = '../mainDir/server.cfc?param1=123&param2=234&method=updateMyInfo';
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType:"text",
    success: function( data ) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) {
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

Comment: ReadyState zero means "The object has been created, but not initialized (the open method has not been called)."

Comment: BTW when I check my DB the changes are there. That means the server side code ran but only the ajax went to Error callback instead of success.

Comment: how do you call the page with this code? via `http/s` or via `file` protocol?

Comment: I call it via http. Using my browser.

Comment: So look at the server and see why it's returning an error?

Comment: @DaveNewton The server is returning the string as expected: '29148'. Another strange thing is that when I hit the ajax call URL directly from my browser, it works fine.

Comment: You'd need to look directly at the response to check for the HTTP response code/etc.

Comment: Any solution...?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are running the page without deploying into server. So ajax request is taken as Cross domain call.