# jQuery.post not working

Tags: jquery, intel-xdk

I'm trying to build a HTML5 mobile app using Intel XDK.
For some reason, when I emulate on the Intel XDK it works but when I try it on a real device I get the error alert

> `http://localhost` The following error occured:
>   {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

```
request = $.ajax({
                    url: "http://domain.com/form.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData
                });

                // callback handler that will be called on success
                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
//do stuff
                });

                // callback handler that will be called on failure
                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // log the error to the console
                    alert(
                        "The following error occured: "+
                        JSON.stringify(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
                    );
                });
```

Comment: I think there is a server side error. Can you share some server side code? Can you debug it yourself?

Comment: the server side PHP code is fine because I have a desktop website which works completely fine off the server side PHP code. The problem is that I'm trying to make a mobile app and the request fails in the mobile app. The request succeeds in the desktop website. However, the desktop websites runs on the server itself, so perhaps this is a cross-site scripting problem? But I thought this isn't cross-site scripting because it's running off a mobile app, not a separate server.

Comment: So, what are you posting? Does it influence handling on the server? Can there be a bug there?

Comment: are you posting to the same domain?

Comment: I checked the serializedData that I'm posting to the server and it's fine. I'm posting from a HTML5 mobile app to the domain.

Comment: What puzzles me is that in the alert, the 'title' of the alert is http://localhost, despite the fact that I'm not trying to use localhost from the HTML5 mobile app since that wouldn't make sense. The server side code starts off with `<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name")` which is the only time localhost appears in my code.

Comment: I think that this is a same origin policy problem. I think that my mobile app 'thinks' that it's the server `http://localhost`, so it doesn't want to connect to the foreign server `http://domain.com` and thus I should solve the problem using solutions like jsonp.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555285 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395354

Answer (score 0):

It is probably failing because of cross-origin request, you have to add these script tags to work around the cross-origin error in Intel XDK apps:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
```

actual script files are not required, you just need to add the above script tags to `index.html` it will be automatically included in Intel XDK builds. Here is more [details](http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps).

Comment: It seems that include xhr.js affect local file loading. I'm having a lot of trouble with xhr. If I include it I can do server call but I cannot se css and load links, viceversa if I don't include it... someone are experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I forget to mention that I'm using angular routeProvider and $location.url("/login"); to load files